# Unreadable block in multiblock reading on dd / ddrescue: How does it handle it?

Tags: data-recovery, dd, storage, ddrescue, optical-media

Let's say that I set the block size of dd or ddrescue to 256K.

A sector of flash drives usually has 512 bytes, a sector on optical data discs has 2048 bytes.

Let's assume that in the next 256 KB, **just one sector is unreadable.** Every other sector is readable.

#### What happens to the multiblock transfer?

- Does it transfer anything at all?
- Does it transfer the readable parts as usual?

It would be great if it did transfer **all readable blocks** as usual.

Comment: I tested it myself. Unfortunately, one error in the entire block size makes it unuseable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example command without abbreviating options/switches:

`sudo ddrescue --direct --sector-size=20480 --verbose --verbose --retry-passes="-1" /dev/sr5`

If one out of the ten sectors in the 20480 next bytes is damaged, **the entire 20480 bytes will not be saved.**

Finer grain: `sudo ddrescue --direct --sector-size=2048 --verbose --verbose --retry-passes="-1" /dev/sr5`

Sending a request for each sector might put a cap on the reading speed. However, ddrescue is lesser about speed than about recoverability. But it can also be seen as a **more comfortable, convenient and verbose** version of *`dd`*.

Note: A second --verbose adds more verbosity, according to the manual at `man ddrescue`.